# The coefficient of $t^n$ in $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t^k\right)^r$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions

I'm trying to count the number of ways of writing a general natural number $n\geq 2$ as the sum of $r$ smaller numbers where each of these numbers is at least $2$ - that is, I want to count the number of $\left\{2,\dots , n\right\}$-restricted $r$-[compositions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n$. This is not an area I expected to find myself when attempting this problem (which started out as a hard group theory exercise), but I've done some research into working with these things via [generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) (see http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~rg/ordgenfct.pdf for a nice intro).

Essentially I need to calculate the coefficient of $t^n$ in the sum $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} t^k\right)^r$ for general $r \leq \left\lfloor n/2 \right\rfloor$ and my brain has completely shut off. Induction on $r$ would be the obvious thing to try but I haven't thought of any hypotheses which would work nicely. Some things which might help you spot a pattern:

$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t^k\right)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{2 n - 3} k t^{k+1}$

$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}t^k\right)^3 = \sum_{k=1}^{3 n - 5} \Delta_k t^{k+2}$ where $\Delta_k$ is the $k$th triangular number

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe the lower limit on $k$ for the inside sum should be $2$ so you get only numbers $2$ or more.

Comment: What about this? "Number of ways of writing $n$ as sum of $r$ smaller numbers, each at least $2$" = "number of ways of writing $n-2r$ as sum of $r$ smaller numbers, each at least $0$" = ${(n-2r)+(r-1)\choose r-1} = {n-r-1\choose r-1}$.

Comment: @jflipp ah of course! Thanks - you've saved me a lot of time and effort